# what does type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>?' means?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone please let me know where im doing wrong and what changes have to be done in the code in order to overcome this error of  **'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream?'**.Earlier the error was like **Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'** for which i wrapped the wwidget undet the StreamBuilder.Doing so resulted in this error.

The below is the code which results in this error

```
class _StudentDashboardState extends State<StudentDashboard> {
  userdetails userdetail;
  String res;

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final CollectionReference student_details =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students');
  final CollectionReference tutor_details =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tutors");

  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  displayPercentage() async {
    var percentage = 0.0;
    var totalClassesTook;
    var totalClassesAttended;
    try {
      totalClassesTook = await tutor_details.doc(uid).get().then((doc) async {
        var val = await doc.data()['TotalClassesTook'];
        return val;
      });

      totalClassesTook = await totalClassesTook == null ? 0 : totalClassesTook;

      totalClassesAttended =
          await student_details.doc(uid).get().then((doc) async {
        var val = await doc.data()['TotalClassesAttended'];
        return val;
      });
      totalClassesAttended =
          await totalClassesAttended == null ? 0 : totalClassesAttended;
      percentage =
          await ((totalClassesAttended / totalClassesTook) * 100.0) / 100.0;
    } catch (e) {
      percentage = 0.0;
    }
    return Center(
      child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 150.0),
          child: new CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 120.0,
            lineWidth: 13.0,
            animation: true,
            percent: percentage,
            center: new Text(
              "$percentage",
              style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            footer: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              child: new Text(
                "Attendance Percentage",
                style:
                    new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
              ),
            ),
            circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
            progressColor: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: displayPercentage(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                  title: Text('Student Welcome'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          await _auth.signOut();
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
                   
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text('Logout'))
              ],
            ),
            body: 
                displayPercentage(),
          );
        }),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `displayPercentage` function is marked as `async` which makes whatever the function returns `wrapped` into a `Future` automaticallu.

You are returning a `Widget` which makes the function's return type `Future<Widget>`. But since you have not mentioned it specifically while defining the function, `dart` is assuming it to `Future<dynamic>`.

Now, coming to your `StreamBuilder`, the parameter `stream` is supposed to be assigned a `Stream`. But you are assigning it your function which is actually a `Future<dynamic>`.

This is why it is giving the error saying that, it expects a `Stream<dynamic>` but you are giving it a `Future<dynamic>` and since `Future` is not a `sub class` that extends from `Stream`, the error says `Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Stream<dynamic>`.

To fix this, change your `StreamBuilder` into a `FutureBuilder` like this,

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: displayPercentage(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          
          // since futures dont immediately give a value, if data is null the show loader
          if (snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();

          // Since data is not null, we can return Scaffold
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
              title: Text('Student Welcome'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // await _auth.signOut();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text('Logout'))
              ],
            ),
            // Since your Future holds the Center widget that you are sending, use it like this
            body: snapshot.data, 
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: great! That worked. But `var val = await doc.data()['TotalClassesAttended'];` in the displayPercentage() function changes dynamically , those realtime changes will reflect by using FutureBuilder? If not what is the alternative please let me know

Comment: In that case, you would still need to use `StreamBuilder` but you should get the `snapshot` instead of `data`. I suggest once you go thorugh the docs for getting realtime updates. If it is confusing tell me, Ill update the answer.

Comment: i have gone through the doc of StreamBuilder, but I'm a bit confused how can i use this in my case,in my code as im calling a displayPercentage() function. I'm unable to call the same function in "stream" of StreamBuilder.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I will create a chat room and tell you there.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232816/discussion

Comment: I must have atleast 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to be able to join chatroom?

Comment: I have upvoted your question, you must be more than 20 now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232820/discussion-between-learn-and-nisanth-reddy).